# Showing equivalence on surjective maps

Tags: abstract-algebra

If  $R$ is  a ring with $1$ and $M$ a uniserial left $R-$module and $\alpha,\beta\in End_R(M)$.

Is it true that $\alpha\beta$ is surjective if and only if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are surjective and why please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does uniserial imply finite length?

Comment: $M$ is said uniserial  if the poset of submodules of $M$ is a chain